Peticion AJAX a una ruta servidor nodejs, POST con data: formData llega undefined
hago una consulta, estoy tratando acceder por una ruta de un servidor nodejs a traves de una ruta a una funcion. La misma recibe datos de un formulario pero llega con el formData.body {} vacio.
------------------------------------------------------------------------  este es el codigo que me daba problema
    $.ajax({
      url: "http://localhost:5300/cotizacion",
      type: 'POST',
      data: formData,
      processData: false,
      contentType: false,
      success: function(response) {
         console.log(response)
      },
      error: function() {
          console.log('Error get precios');
      }
  });

recibio emn JSON.
var consulta = {
"_id":"",
"variable1": valor_1,
"variable1":valor2,
}
      $.ajax({
          url: "http://localhost:5300/cotizacion", 
          data: JSON.stringify(consulta),
          type: "POST",
          contentType: 'application/json',
          dataType: "json",
          success: function(response) {
              console.log(response);
          },
          error: function() {
              console.log("Error al obtener precios");
          }
      });
      

Es una secuencia de peticiones AJAX donde una tiene el mismo formData, que se usa en un envio de mail. Lo e puesto en varias ubicaciones, y el resultado es el mismo. Tambien probe con el data, que es un json. Las peticiones GET funcionan bien. Estuve probando enviando texto, si me pueden ¿Como seria la peticion AJAX si lo recibiera esta funcion const getPrecios = async (texto) => {
console.log(texto); // Aquí puedes realizar cualquier operación que desees con el texto
alert(texto); // Muestra el texto en una alerta
};
Hago peticiones desde el front-end en ANGULAR y funciona bien
Gracias por sus comentarios, me serán de gran ayuda. ,

Tendrías que añadir el código de donde llamas a getPrecios, así es imposible saber por que es undefined

En la peticion los datos los envías en la propiedad data y los recibes en la propiedad body. Deberías enviarlos en la propiedad body

gracias, publique como resolvi,
